# Overload Function Call Operator in a Class

Tags: c++

In the .h file given to me by my professor, he's written

```
    double operator()(double x) const;
```

The point of the overload is to read in x as a double and use it to evaluate a polynomial that's stored in the class object Term.  What I've come up with in the class implementation is

```
    double operator()(double x) const
    {   double result = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < getSize(); i++)
            result += (getCoeff(i) * pow(x, getExponent(i)));
        return result;
    }
```

How do I call it from the application?  I've tried different calls like

```
    Polynomial p;
    p.operator(x);
```

or

```
    Polynomial::operator(x);
```

or

```
    operator(x);
```

but always get errors when compiling.

Comment: Check this: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/99-overloading-the-parenthesis-operator/

Answer (score 4):

The usual form is to call it as if your instance was a function:

```
double x = 3.1416;
Polynomial p;
double y = p(x);
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly call the operator:

```
double x = 3.1416;
Polynomial p;
double y = p.operator()(x);
```

Here's a simplified example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
  double operator()(double x) const { return x*2; }
};

int main()
{
  Foo f;
  std::cout << f(2.5) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: When using p(x) I get the error "expected unqualified-id before '(' token".  And p.operator()(x) gives several errors.

Comment: @user2841264 well, that's the way to call the operator, so you must have another error. Obviously this assumes that you have declared `x`, and set it to something.

Comment: @user2841264 - Read what line the error is caused by. Don't assume it's the thing you fixed.